# Linked List delete operation not working in visual studio using C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

when I tried to implement a linked list in visual studio 2019 using c it produces heap error.
It was due to the free function.
However, the code works fine on online compilers which use the GCC compiler. https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler/

I can't able to figure it out..........................

[image]

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head = NULL;

void append(int data)
{

    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    (*newNode).data = data;
    (*newNode).next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    struct Node* temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newNode;
}

void insertAt(int position, int data)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;



    if (position == 1)
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    struct Node* temp = head;

    for (int i = 1; i < position - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
}

void deleteAt(int position)
{
    struct Node* temp = NULL;

    if (position == 1)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    struct Node* tempHead = head;

    for (int i = 1; i < position - 1; i++)
    {
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }

    temp = tempHead->next;
    tempHead->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);


}

void print()
{
    struct Node* temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

void main()
{
    append(3);
    append(4);
    append(5);
    append(6);

    insertAt(3, 20);
    insertAt(4, 50);
    insertAt(2, 70);

    deleteAt(4);
    deleteAt(3);


    print();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizes you're passing to `malloc` are wrong.  You should pass `sizeof(struct Node)`.

If you're compiling this as C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all.

Answer (score 2):

As [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61805048/2410359) answered, the allocation size is wrong.  `sizeof(struct Node*)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the `struct`.

Instead of trying to match the type, use the size of the referenced data.  Easy to code right, review and maintian.

Cast not needed in C.

```
// struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
// instead... 
//  ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N);
struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code once down there .This code is written by me according to my understanding and still if u have any issue with the code you can further ask me .You can try this code out or just cross check it with your's.

Code:

Linked List:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;
void create(int A[],int n)
{
 int i;
 struct Node *t,*last;
 first=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 first->data=A[0];
 first->next=NULL;
 last=first;

 for(i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
 t=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 t->data=A[i];
 t->next=NULL;
 last->next=t;
 last=t;
 }
}
void Display(struct Node *p)
{
 while(p!=NULL)
 {
 printf("%d ",p->data);
 p=p->next;
 }
}
void RDisplay(struct Node *p)
{
 if(p!=NULL)
 {
 RDisplay(p->next);
 printf("%d ",p->data);

 }
}
int Delete(struct Node *p,int index)
{
 struct Node *q=NULL;
 int x=-1,i;

 if(index < 1 || index > count(p))
 return -1;
 if(index==1)
 {
 q=first;
 x=first->data;
 first=first->next;
 free(q);
 return x;
 }
 else
 {
 for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
 {
 q=p;
 p=p->next;
 }
 q->next=p->next;
 x=p->data;
 free(p);
 return x;

 }


}
int main()
{

 int A[]={10,20,30,40,50};
 create(A,5);

 printf(“%d\n",Delete(first),2);
 Display(first);

 return 0;
}
```

In main function you can pass the function created int the program and also pass the argument according to you.